# File or directory _findfirst C++

Tags: c++, windows, file, directory

I'm writing program which lists all files and subdirectories in particular directory and returns size occupied by directory. 
I use to this purpose functions _findfirst64 and _findnext64

How can I know if object is a file or directory?

Comment: This should probably be tagged 'C' rather than 'C++'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda16keh.aspx

Information about the found object is in the second argument, `struct _finddata_t`.

```
_finddata_t_ info;
intptr_t handle = _findfirst64("myfile", &info);
if (handle > 0)
{
    if (info->attrib & _A_SUBDIR) 
    {
        // it's a directory
```